# Why does this pointer/integer comparison generate a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am working on a program which generates a segmentation fault and I cannot understand why. If I remove the pointer declaration from "lowest" and "largest" variables and use them as pointerless integers the program works fine.

However, as soon as I try to use pointers, problems arise and I receive a segmentation fault. I realize that this is probably a very easy and well addressed issue, but I've tried to understand the code by looking on other similar problems. I haven't found a solution for my problem yet. Nor do I understand what's going wrong.

This is the code generating the problem (link to full source is below):

```
     cout << "This is the array containing the random numbers:\n";
 for(int *i=numbers; i != numbers + arrLength; i++) {
     if((*i % 200) == 0 && *i > 200) {
         cin.get();
         cout << endl;
     }
     else
         cout << *i << ' ';

     // Get statistics
     // In the continuation of getting, lowest, largest then adding to sum.
     // THIS PART IS MAKING SEGMENTATION FAULT.
     if(*i < *lowest)
         lowest =  i;
     if(*i > *largest)
         largest = i;
     sum += *i;
 }
```

The `i` variable points to an old reference which is declared after user input:

```
cout << "You entered: " << arrLength << "\n\n";

 int *numbers = new int[arrLength];

 // Fill the array with random numbers
 srand(time(NULL));
 int x;
 int range = 5001;
 for(int index=0; index<arrLength; index++){
     *(numbers + index) = rand() % range;
     x = rand() % 2;
     if(x > 0) {
         *(numbers + index) = *(numbers + index) * -1;
     }
 }
```

Please explain to be why my program isn't working and what I am doing wrong. As I've said earlier everything works except the:

```
if(*i < *lowest)
         lowest =  i;
     if(*i > *largest)
         largest = i;
```

Full source:
http://pastie.org/2105963

Thanks in advance on this matter!

Comment: why do you use complicated pointer arithmetic instead of using the array access operator `[index]`?

Comment: @knittl: It's probably C++ homework and the professor is teaching them pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising lowest and largest to 0 and the dereference is accessing memory via a null pointer and so it falls over. Try this instead:

```
if (!lowest || *i < *lowest)
    lowest =  i;
if (!largest || *i > *largest)
    largest = i;
```

or:

```
int *numbers = new int[arrLength];
lowest = largers = numbers; // initialise to something non-null
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works perfect and I understand what I did wrong. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
int *largest = 0, *lowest = 0, sum = 0;
```

This is your problem. You never allocate memory or assign a valid address to these. And when you dereference a NULL pointer, like here

```
if(*i < *lowest) //lowest is NULL
```

you get Undefined Behavior, which includes segmentation fault, nasal demons, and anything else

Comment: Thanks, now it works perfect and I understand what I did wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work, because it doesn't compare pointers. You are comparing the values stored at some memory addresses, which most likely don't belong to your program, therefore you are shot down by a SIGSEGV.

You can't access memory that doesn't belong to your program.

Answer (score 1):

are `lowest` and `largest` initialized before you dereference them? Using `*lowest` will cause a seg fault if lowest doesn't point to a valid address.

you can try setting `lowest = largest = numbers;` somewhere at the start. Maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your programming is using invalid memory (lowest and largest pointer).
But !

**Pointers are not necessary in this code**

In fact the program has an unrequired complexity.
Why using pointer, when you can use indices ?

You will problably found your allocation/initialisation error.

```
 for(int index=0; index<arrLength; index++){
     numbers[index] = rand() % range;
     x = rand() % 2;
     if(x > 0) {
         numbers[index] = numbers[index] * -1;
     }
 }
```

You need only a pointer to create the array.

```
int *numbers = new int[arrayLength];
```

And finally your program will be simpler :

```
int lowest =numbers[0], largest = lowest;
 for(int i=0; i < arrLength; i++) {
     int ii = numbers[i ];                      )
     if((ii % 200) == 0 && ii > 200) {
         cin.get();
         cout << endl;
     }
     else
         cout << ii << ' ';

     if(ii < lowest)
         lowest =  ii;
     if(ii > largest)
         largest = ii;
     sum += ii;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the lowest & largest value pointers to 0 then dereferencing them later without pointing them to a valid value.

```
int *largest = 0, *lowest = 0, sum = 0;
```